# How to concatenate vectors forming a matrix and padding with zeros

Tags: matlab, octave

I'd like to concatenate 2 or more vectors of different lengths in a matrix and filling the remaining positions with zeros.

For example, let's suppose I have a vector of 3 elements and another one of 4. I'd want to create a (2x4) matrix that contains the second vector aforementioned and the first one with a zero at the end.

I have tried using this:

```
v1 = [1 2 3];
v2 = [1 2 3 4];
M(1,:) = v1; M(2,:) = v2;
%and also cat(1,v1,v2) and cat(3,v1,v2)
```

But it didn't work. I also have to take into account that I don't know the number of elements of the second vector (the matrix will be formed in a for loop adding each vector to a row of the matrix).

I hope someone can help me. Thank you for your responses.

Comment: sounds like a xy-problem

Comment: What does it mean?

Comment: @Josemi  You are almost there, declare M in the (new) first line: M=zeros(2,4) and modify the first item in the last line to M(1,1:3)=v1

Comment: @Josemi: Have you tried to google it?

Answer (score 1):

```
M = zeros(2,max(length(v1),length(v2)));
M(1,1:length(v1)) = v1;
M(2,1:length(v2)) = v2;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
v1 = [1 2 3];
v2 = [1 2 3 4 5 6 7];
mxl=max(numel(v1),numel(v2))
m=[[v1 zeros(1,mxl-numel(v1))]; [v2 zeros(1,mxl-numel(v2))]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Although I think this is a typical xy-problem here a more general solution for more than one vector:

```
v{1} = [1 2 3];
v{2} = [10 20 30 40];
v{3} = [8 9];
ml = max (cellfun ("numel", v));
M = cat (1, cellfun (@(c) postpad (c, ml, 0), v, "UniformOutput", false){:})
M =
    1    2    3    0
   10   20   30   40
    8    9    0    0
```